# Dirac notation when bra and ket aren't vectors

Tags: quantum-chemistry

So, I know that
$$
\langle \psi_j(x)|\psi_k(x) \rangle =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_j^*(x) \psi_k(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and I was wondering that if this is because of the inner product rule as with vectors? Like $\langle a|b \rangle$, but the $\psi$ isn't a vector, so how would this work in this case?

Answer (score 10):

Wave function for a quantum system is a vector in a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), which is a special kind of an [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space). Specifically, for a spin-0 particle constrained to move in 1 spatial dimension the wave function $\psi(x)$ is an element of [$L^2(\mathbf{R})$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Special_cases), i.e. the space of functions that are [square-integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function) on the whole real line $\mathbf{R} = (-\infty;+\infty)$. And the inner product between any two elements $\vec{\psi}_{i} = \psi_i(x)$ and $\vec{\psi}_{j} = \psi_j(x)$ of $L^2(\mathbf{R})$ space is indeed defined as follows,
$$
\newcommand{\inner}[2]{\langle{#1},{#2}\rangle}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\,\lvert{#1}\rangle}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle{#1}\vert{#2}\rangle}
\inner{\vec{\psi}_{i}}{\vec{\psi}_{j}} := \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi_i^*(x) \psi_j(x)\, \mathrm{d} x \, .
$$

---

Just note here that, first, it is the matter of convention in which argument the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) is linear: in physical literature it is often defined to be linear in the second argument, while in mathematically oriented literature it is usually defined to be linear in the first argument. Consequently, mathematicians usually define the inner product between any two elements $\psi_i$ and $\psi_j$ of $L^2(\mathbf{R})$ space in the following way,
$$
\inner{\vec{\psi}_{i}}{\vec{\psi}_{j}} := \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi_i(x) \psi_j^*(x)\, \mathrm{d} x \, ,
$$
as it is in fact done in some Wikipedia articles referenced above.

And secondly, physicists usually prefer to use even a different notation, the so-called Dirac [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation), in which elements of a Hilbert space are denoted as $\ket{\psi_i}$ and $\ket{\psi_j}$ (rather than $\vec{\psi}_{i}$ and $\vec{\psi}_{j}$ as it is usually done in linear algebra), while their inner product is designated as $\braket{\psi_i}{\psi_j}$ (rather than $\inner{\vec{\psi}_{i}}{\vec{\psi}_{j}}$).

Comment: or even the more consise  notation $\langle i|k\rangle$

Comment: @porphyrin, yep. Basically, things inside brackets (or underneath arrows) are just *labels*, so they can be virtually anything.